# ng-build - Output files name is always the same

Tags: angular-cli

I'm using the command bellow to build my angular project:

`ng build --prod --aot --output-hashing=all --base-href=...`

When i saw my dist folder, all the files have a hashing in the name, like the image bellow. But, if i made a change in some js files and buld again, the output file name is the same. It's possible to generate a different output file name for each build?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this, but I would imagine that names of each file is generated based on a hash of the content.

This means that as long as the content does not change, then the name does not either.

If it's not the case, then caching might be the issue.

Angular automatically caches the operations in the `.angular` folder at the root of your project.

Simply delete it, see if it resolves the issue.

If not, then it's the first case, and you can't do much about it.

Now that I have answered, I sould also tell you that you're not supposed to edit the JS files afer build, because not only they will probably change at every build, but also it's difficult (and not stable) to automatize this step.